# php - Split an associative array with value greater than some integer

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get specific range of values from an associative array whose values are greater than some integer. So the array in question is like this (of course this is just a small portion of the original array which has like 4000 rows minimum )

```
     "series" : [
     { "Timestamp" :1383921425,"close" :5.4500,"high" :5.4500,"low" :5.4500,"open" :5.4500,"volume" :0 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383921849,"close" :5.5000,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.5000,"open" :5.5000,"volume" :3000 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383922360,"close" :5.5300,"high" :5.5300,"low" :5.5300,"open" :5.5300,"volume" :3200 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383922507,"close" :5.4700,"high" :5.4700,"low" :5.4700,"open" :5.4700,"volume" :200 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383923037,"close" :5.5000,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.5000,"open" :5.5000,"volume" :500 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383923297,"close" :5.5000,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.5000,"open" :5.5000,"volume" :0 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383923891,"close" :5.5400,"high" :5.5400,"low" :5.5300,"open" :5.5400,"volume" :6000 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383924237,"close" :5.5400,"high" :5.5400,"low" :5.5400,"open" :5.5400,"volume" :0 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383924468,"close" :5.4400,"high" :5.4400,"low" :5.4400,"open" :5.4400,"volume" :2600 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383925088,"close" :5.4500,"high" :5.4500,"low" :5.4500,"open" :5.4500,"volume" :1500 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383926006,"close" :5.5000,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.5000,"open" :5.5000,"volume" :6800 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383926397,"close" :5.4900,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.4900,"open" :5.5000,"volume" :7200 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383926581,"close" :5.5000,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.5000,"open" :5.5000,"volume" :300 } 
    , { "Timestamp" :1383926970,"close" :5.5000,"high" :5.5000,"low" :5.4900,"open" :5.4900,"volume" :2100 } 
]
```

Here i want to extract the rows whose "Timestamp" value is greater than some integer. Now this integer is being extracted from another array, which is like this

```
    "TimeStamp-Ranges" : [
{ "date" :20131108, "min" :1383921000, "max" :1383922360}
,{ "date" :20131111, "min" :1383922507, "max" :1383923891}
,{ "date" :20131112, "min" :1383924237, "max" :1383926006}

]
```

So i want to extract the rows from the array  named "series" whose "Timestamp" values are greater than TimeStamp-Ranges[1]["min"].

Of course i can do it easily using `foreach()` , but i want to use php's built in array function just for the performance benefits.

So far i've written this much of code, but i'm getting an error when i run this

Here is the code

```
array_filter($this->JSON_data->series, function($minValue) use ($this->JSON_data->series and $this->JSON_data->{"TimeStamp-Ranges"}) {

                return ($this->JSON_data->series->Timestamp > $this->JSON_data->{"TimeStamp-Ranges"}[count($this->JSON_data->{"TimeStamp-Ranges"}) - 1]->min);
            })
```

Please, provide any sort of tips or guide on how could i do this efficiently, and again i'm emphasizing performance reasons because this needs to be done realtime and this array manipulation may occur several thousands time in each seconds.

Thanks, in advance. Any help is appreciated.
Maxx

Comment: "I want to use php's built in array function just for the performance benefits" - why do you think there will be performance benefits? There functions have a loop inside anyway. You want to search in a non-sorted array. You will have to use O(n) algorithm. Use foreach without hesitation and don't over complicate the task.

Comment: General tip: If you get an error message, TELL US what it is.

Comment: @user4035 Thanks for the reply. The reason as to why i mentioned that because i saw in some other post in SO that PHP's built in functions are precompiled and kept as binary format enabling PHP to access them much faster.. Although i don't know how much truth are in those statements

Comment: @Marc B Sorry for not mentioning.. The errors  that i'm getting are $this->JSON_data->series and $this->JSON_data->{"TimeStamp-Ranges"} cannot be accessed inside the anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is some kind of cheesy solution but I don't have PHP above 5.2.7 so bear with me

#### a unique solution to a unique problem

for performance reasons this may be better converted into a static solution

```
<?php
class ComplicatedFilterForComplicatedArray {
  private $cond, $series;
  function __construct($json) {$this->series = $json->series;}
  function filterByRange(array $jsonRanges, $idx, $by='min') {
    $this->cond = $jsonRanges[$idx]->{$by};
    return array_filter($this->series,array($this,'filterFn'));
  }
  function filterFn($v) {return $v->timestamp > $this->cond;}
}
```

#### usage

```
$f = new ComplicatedFilter($json_series);
$filteredSeries = $f->filterByRange($json_ts_ranges,1,'min');
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated, and again, I'm sorry this is not on par with such elegant solutions *a la* `PHP > 5.3`

Comment: Yes using this solution works fine. I knew that there must be some clear soultion to this problem, which this solution provides. Thanks a lot for this. Much appreciated. And funny function name btw :-)

Comment: And about peformance, this solution performs surprisingly well for a huge dataset. So again many thanks for this.